# Excel Immediate Window Print Formula Value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Today is my first day writing Excel macro and I was given a task to modify someone else's' code to add new features.  I learn Excel has a Immediate window which I am finding very useful.

I do have a question that I am unable to find the answer to in the last hour of searching.  If you look at the image below you will notice that `fstr` is a string variable.

[image]

Currently, `fstr` holds a formula.  How can I print out actual value of this formula instead of the formula itself?

One thing I tried was `fstr.xlPastValues`, but it didn't work. I got this idea from recording a macro while pasting a value of a formula manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Evaluate method:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim sFormula As String
    sFormula = "=A1+A2"
    'evaluate in the context of the current worksheet
    '  adjust to suit...
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Evaluate(sFormula)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks again. this was such a life saver by looking at all the values in an external file. i can now get some sleep tonight.